# How to use string value as a column selector in a for loop

Tags: r

I have a for loop that looks like this

```
for (j in c("Month_1", "Month_2", "Month_3", "Month_4")) {
  r <- ggplot(df_tableAcc[df_tableAcc$j > 100,]) + 
    aes_string(x = "ShipSog") + 
    geom_bar()
  
  print(r)
}
```

Where the column names in df_tableAcc is "Month_1", "Month_2", "Month_3", "Month_4".

How can I use the "[df_tableAcc$**j** > 100," ?

I keep getting this error:

> Warning: Unknown or uninitialised column: `j`.
> Error: Must subset rows with a valid subscript vector. i Logical subscripts must match the
> size of the indexed input. x Input has size 1852 but subscript
> `df_tableAcc$j > 100` has size 0.

Comment: Try `df[[j]]`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `df_tableAcc$j` to `df_tableAcc[[j]]`:

```
for (j in c("Month_1", "Month_2", "Month_3", "Month_4")) {
  r <- ggplot(df_tableAcc[df_tableAcc[[j]] > 100,]) + 
    aes_string(x = "ShipSog") + 
    geom_bar()
  
  print(r)
}
```